# How to get the confidence of a Sphinx4 result hypothesis?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, sphinx4

I'm using Sphinx4 as a word reconizer. I've made a little dictionnary and a little grammar for the few words that i want to reconize.
The `SpeechResult result.getHypothesis()` method works fine when i say a word from my grammar but it always give me a grammar result even if I make a sound or I say a random word.

My question is: Is there a way to test the accuracy of the hypothesis? To know if the word said by the user is actually in my grammar or not.

For example imagine a grammar with a single word: car.
Is there a way to have a binary result: "user said car"/ "user didn't say car"?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sphinx4 ConfidenceResult and SpeechResult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517104/sphinx4-confidenceresult-and-speechresult)

Comment: That question above is on the same subject

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you forgot to enable using the grammar:

`configuration.setUseGrammar(true);`

Or something similar.
To get the confidence you have to use ConfidenceScorer.
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/result/ConfidenceScorer.html